# Upstream O2 sensor HELP

Tags: hyundai

I have a 2014 Hyundai Accent GLS. I Have to replace the upstream O2 sensor. I bought a new one that claims it is universal. When I cut the wires to connect them, the o2 sensor that came out of my car has 5 wires. The universal has 4. How can I wire them together? Is it possible to put two wires together and connect them to one wire on the universal sensor? Or do I have to buy a different o2 sensor.

Comment: You have to find out what each of the 5 wires do and also what each of the 4 sensor wires do and then work out how to do the connection. It may, of course, not be possible but if you cut the wires off the new sensor they may not refund it...

Comment: Send the universal part back and get the right part.

Comment: In short you can't wire them together, it's not a narrowband o2s. Like GdD says send it back and get the correct part for your car.

Answer (score 1):

The one you bought might be "universal" for the *downstream* "secondary" sensor.  (HO2S B1S2)

The upstream sensor is a wideband 5-wire as Ben mentions and is *completely* incompatible with a 4-wire unit.  Different voltages, technology, etc.

You're going to need the proper sensor.